# Why do we insert “Karban” on this line of Al Cheit?

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur, viduy-confession

In the lengthy “Al Cheit” section of Yom Kippur Vidui, there is a section that reads as follows:

> ועל חטאים שאנו חייבים עליהם עולה
>
> ועל חטאים שאנו חייבים עליהם חטאת
>
> ועל חטאים שאנו חייבים עליהם קרבן עולה ויורד
>
> ועל חטאים שאנו חייבים אשם ודאי ותלוי

This list gives four Karbanos, but only the Oleh v’yored is prefixed by the word “Karban.” Why? Why not just say שאנו חייבים עליהם עולה ויורד?

---

The following places are among several where it’s not referred to with the title Karban. It should be noted, though, that often it takes the title; my question is why, since we see that it often doesn’t, is it singled out here.

Shevuos 6b-7a:

> אימא ה"מ קרבן קבוע אבל עולה ויורד ניתי מידי דהוה אשמיעת קול ואביטוי שפתים

Shevuos 8a:

> אימא יולדת דחלק דמייתא עולה ויורד

Kerisos 22b:

> מה להלן בקבועה אף כאן בקבועה לאפוקי עולה ויורד דלא

Toras Kohanim, Acharei Mos 4:4:

> ומנין לשיש בה ידיעה בתחלה ואין בה ידיעה בסוף שתולה לו עד שיתודע לו ויביא עולה ויורד

Yerushalmi Shevuos 4a:

> אמר לו ע"ז בקבוע וטומאת מקדש וקדשיו בעולה ויורד ואין למידין קבוע מעולה ויורד ולא עולה ויורד מקבוע

Comment: Because an עולה ויורד is a Yoyo. :-)

Comment: You've just shifted the question. You've established that sometimes it does and sometimes doesn't go by the shorthand version. Now the question is why does it change? Al Cheit is just one example among many and there's no reason to focus in it or probably even cite it.

Comment: Incidentally most of your examples don't even work since it's just contrasting the adjective Kavua with Oleh veYored, or in English contrasting "fixed" and "variable". Neither is a name. (I haven't looked them all up inside.) So you should remove those examples since they are quite misleading